# Development environment Gradle & Docker without compiling jar's and rebuilding containers

Tags: java, spring, docker, gradle

I am relatively new to Java, Gradle, Spring and Docker, and i need to perform some modifications on an open source project: https://github.com/streamaserver/streama written in Java.

I have set up a dev environment but i don't believe that this is the optimal approach, can this be done more efficiently without the need to rebuild with Gradle and rebuild docker containers on every code change?

This is what i run at the moment to get Docker up listening on localhost  with a fresh build

```
./gradlew build 
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up
```

Does the gradle project have to be compiled in to a jar file?

Can the docker container sync with filesystem and listen to changed to the jar?

Comment: simply call `docker-compose` with a Gradle `Exec` task, which finalizes the last one task.

Comment: Task 'exec' not found in root project 'streama'